# Quickbooks webconnector error parsing xml

Tags: xml, quickbooks

**Can you give some advice on how to have the invoices from Quickbooks web Connector?**

I have Quickbooks Enterprise 4.0 and webconnector 2.1. Version US.

I use this xml

```
<?qbxml version="3.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceQueryRq  requestID="invoice" iterator="Start">
              <MaxReturned>100</MaxReturned>
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

**Webconnector say:**

*QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.*

*hresult: 0x80040400*

---

If use xml without iterator attribute

```
<?qbxml version="3.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceQueryRq  requestID="invoice">
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Then Quickbooks enterprise 4.0 response with error because there are many rows.

**Can you give some advice on how to have the invoices from Quickbooks web Connector?**

---

Quickbooks say that support iterators in MAX SDK 3.0

[image: qbXML page]

Why not work iterators with Quickbooks Enterprise 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The OSR reference is apparently incorrect - your version of QuickBooks is too old to support iterators. You need to upgrade to a newer version of QuickBooks, or not use iterators.*

If you refer to the documentation (set the qbXML version to your version, `3.0`):

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf  (go to page 76)

You'll find this blurb:

> There are two ways to limit the data returned from a query. The best way is to use the 
>   iterator feature, which is specific to queries. This feature is available only to desktop 
>   editions QB 2006 and later using qbXML spec 5.0 and greater.

QuickBooks 2004/qbXML version `3.0` (a version of QuickBooks that is 10 years old now...) does not support iterators.

The solution - either don't use iterators (the `iterator="Start"` line you have) or upgrade to a version of QuickBooks that supports them.

Comment: Please view my question.

Comment: Link updated, see page 76 of the linked PDF for details on what versions do and do not support iterators. Apparently the OSR is showing this incorrectly. My answer is still correct - your version of QuickBooks does not support iterators. Upgrade or don't use them.